# Efficient banner rotation with PHP

Tags: php, random, rotation, banner

I rotate a banner on my site by selecting it randomly from an array of banners.

Sample code as demonstration:

```
<?php
$banners = array(
'<iframe>...</iframe>',
'<a href="#"><img src="#.jpg" alt="" /></a>',
//and so on
);
echo $banners(rand(0, count($banners)));
?>
```

The array of banners has become quite big. I am concerned with the amount of memory that this array adds to the execution of my page.
But I can't figure out a better way of showing a random banner without loading all the banners into memory...

Comment: are you banners stored in a database? if so you could use sql random ;)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the banners to html files and change the array to contain only filenames.

Then you can include that file by the name, only loading the banner required.

Comment: I like this idea best. It will add more work than a database, but it's easier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Create a database to store the banners in. Then when you do your page load, you could use a SQL query to select a random row.

```
SELECT * FROM banners ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If I did this with MySQL, it would add another query to the page load. Having another query would outweigh the advantage of saving some memory on the page load. DanMan, I only discovered SQLLite recently. But I guess it would be a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without requiring array memory or a database, is to follow an incremental image naming convention, for example naming your images "banner1.jpg", "banner2.jpg", etc.  Then you can just do this:

```
$int_banners = 10;  // the number of banner images you have
$i = rand(1, $int_banners);
echo "<a href='#'><img src='banner$i.jpg' alt=''></a>";  // add an iframe too if you want
```

If you cannot use such a convention, then you can create an array with just the file names (or use a SQL database to store the banners, as suggested in other answers).

```
$lst_banners = array("img1.jpg", "/home/img2.jpg", "/about/img3.jpg");
$int_banners = count($lst_banners);
$i = rand(0, ($int_banners - 1));
echo "<a href='#'><img src='" . $lst_banners[$i] . "' alt=''></a>";
```

Or better, you can use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to find the filename, as suggested by [Zlatan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386320/zlatan):

```
$lst_banners = array("img1.jpg", "/home/img2.jpg", "/about/img3.jpg");
$name = array_rand($lst_banners, 1);
echo "<a href='#'><img src='$name' alt=''></a>";
```

Comment: @reggie: Thanks - I didn't really suspect you!