# Banner Rotation (SMF Forum)

Tags: php, html, css

Hi am trying to create a simple banner rotation system for my forum, which uses SMF software.

I read your post here: [Efficient banner rotation with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108097/efficient-banner-rotation-with-php)

I was very impressed with your knowledge.  I have been trying for some time to get my sponsors banners rotating at the top of my forum.  Could you please tell me how to set this up?  I just need some direction on how to implement the changes you described in the link above.  Do I do the changes in the index.php file of my forum?  I have a custom theme, does that mean I only make changes to that index.php file?  Where do I insert the code in the index.php file and how do I get each banner to link to a different website?

I know I have a lot of questions ... any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: what is "SMF software"? Why are you using it? Are you using a CMS for you forum?

Comment: I'm using SMF (Simple Machines Forum) as my forum software.  There is an index.php, I'm sorry if I'm not answering you very well, I'm not at all an expert at this sort of thing.  I use cpanel to acces the php files.